# Facebook Javascript SDK show value of array

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to show the tags of a checkin in facebook javascript sdk, but shows only [object Object] because it is an array, I tried several ways to show this array, but could not.

The following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>New JavaScript SDK</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: '274371602680881', 
                        status: true, 
                        cookie: true,
                        xfbml: true,
                        oauth: true
                    });

                    function updateButton(response) {
                        var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            //user is already logged in and connected
                            var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
                                button.innerHTML = 'Uninstall';

                                FB.api('/me/checkins', function(response) {
                                    console.log('Got your check-ins: ', response);

                                    if (!response.error) {
                                        //displayCheckIns(response.data, document.getElementById('checkins'));

                                        var markup = '<div class="data-header">Your last five check-ins:</div>';

                                        for (var i=0; i < response.data.length && i < 5; i++) {
                                            var checkin = response.data[i];

                                            //alert(checkin.tags);
                                            //alert(checkin.tags.length);
                                            //alert(checkin.tags.name);
                                            //alert(checkin.tags[0]);
                                            //alert(checkin.tags[0].name);

                                            markup += '<div class="place">'
                                                        + '<div class="picture">Foto: <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + checkin.place.id + '/picture"></div>'
                                                        + '<div class="info">'
                                                            + '<div class="from">From: ' + checkin.from.name + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="tags">Tags: ' + checkin.tags + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="place">Place: ' + checkin.place.name + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="place-location">Place Location: ' + checkin.place.location.latitude + ", " + checkin.place.location.longitude + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="application">Application: ' + checkin.application.name + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="created_time">Created time: ' + checkin.created_time + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="likes">Likes: ' + checkin.likes + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="check-in-msg">Mensagem: ' + (checkin.message || '') + '</div>'
                                                            + '<div class="comments">Comments: ' + checkin.comments + '</div>'
                                                        + '</div>'
                                                    + '</div>';
                                        }

                                        document.getElementById('user-checkins').innerHTML = markup;
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            button.onclick = function() {
                                FB.api({
                                    method: 'auth.revokeAuthorization'
                                }, function(response) {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                });
                                /*
                                FB.logout(function(response) {
                                    var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                                    userInfo.innerHTML="";
                                });*/
                            };
                        } else {
                            //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                            button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                            button.onclick = function() {
                                FB.login(function(response) {
                                    if (response.authResponse) {
                                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                            var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                                            userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' + response.name;
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    scope:'user_status'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
                    FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
                };

                (function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                    e.src = document.location.protocol 
                        + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                }());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<h2>Updated JS SDK example</h2><br />
<div id="user-info"></div>
<div id="user-checkins"></div>
<p><button id="fb-auth">Login</button></p>
</body> 
</html>
```

I tried a few ways, such as:

```
checkin.tags // shows [object Object]
checkin.tags.length // shows undefined
checkin.tags.name // shows undefined
checkin.tags[0] // shows undefined
checkin.tags[0].name // Can not read property 'name' of undefined
```

This happens with tags, likes and comments. The others that are NOT array works fine, like "checkin.place.name", and even "checkin.place.location.latitude" brings the correct value.

I did an "console.log(JSON.stringify(checkin.tags));" and it returns:

```
{"data":[{"id":"100001702765878","name":"Mauricio Forte Neto"},{"id":"100001174670611","name":"Mario Celso"}],"paging":{"next":"https://graph.facebook.com/402127889842448/tags?access_token=AAAD5ih3qDDEBAIo3nB8P3ZCAwXrivw5lunDRAUvkRZCCFZBUy5au3ImicViq80HHVZC29hLDit6QwlZCXZB5WEBkDF3Pp2DrnUGWLrAwhpWddLoliyFDqd&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100001174670611"}}
```

Please, help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `checkins` _itself_ is an array, then it _itself_ will have a `length` property, and it _itself_ will allow index-based access. Hint: If you’re not sure about the structure of an object, log it to your browser’s JavaScript console using `console.log` – there you should be able to better see, how it’s actually composed …

Comment: That must be the problem, is an array within another, but on page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/ says it retuns an array, I already put in console.log(checkin.tags), but shows only [object Object]

Comment: What browser are you using? In my Firebug in Firefox, console.log is able to display all kinds of objects, and they are even clickable to see a representation that allows “browsing” through their structure.

Comment: I check again, and I misunderstanding with alert, console.log shows an array with an "browsing" through their structure like you said, but still don't know how to show that :/

Comment: Then maybe you should learn some more JS basic first …? If it shows `Object { foo="bar", … }` there, then it’s an object, whose members you can access by name, object.foo – if it just shows `[1,2,3]`, then it’s an array, and can be accessed by [index].

Comment: that what i telling you... look at the tests i've made... like.. checkin.tags.name // shows undefined.. or.. checkin.tags.length // shows undefined.. or checkin.tags[0] // shows undefined.. or.. checkin.tags[0].name // Can not read property 'name' of undefined.. still doens't work...

Comment: And what exactly does it look like, when you log your object to the console?

Comment: http://i46.tinypic.com/abgo7n.png

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an object and has data in it, I have to request the data type in it.

What I been missing is to add an ".data" like:

```
checkin.tags.data[0].name
```

Now it works!!!